# Push all local branches to origin in git

Tags: git

Let's say that I have A LOT of local branches in my git not pushed on the remote repository.

How can I push all of them to origin with a single command?

Comment: `git push --prune origin +refs/remotes/old-origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Have you tried

```
git push --all -u
```

The git man states

> --all
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under refs/heads/ be pushed.
>
> -u, --set-upstream
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference,

the `-u` is useful if you intent to pull from these branches later

Comment: `$ git push origin --all` worked for me too

Comment: @user3405291 it won't work for remotes that are not "origin", where the accepted answer will

Comment: @riders994 and accepted answer will not work for untracked branches :)

Answer (score 13):

```
git push <remote_name> '*:*'
```

The command is intuitive in that it specifies the `:`. The one on the left of `:` indicates the name of the local branch and the one on the right specifies the remote branch. In your case, we want to map with the same name and thus the command.

The `*:*` tells git that you want to push every local branch to remote with the same name on remote. Thus if you have a branch named `my_branch` you will have a remote branch named `<remote_name>/my_branch`.

So typically you would do `git push origin '*:*'` and you would find every local branch with the same name in the remote, which you can confirm by `git branch -r` which will show you all the remote branches.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [*refspec*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) that tells git to push all your branches:

```
git push origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```