# Why origin/head shows in a repo but not in other?

Tags: git

I made a local git repo(git init), and made some commits in it.

Then I made a repo on github and made my local repo colaborate with it:

> git remote add origin url-of-my-remote-gitrepo

I pushed the local commits to remote git repo:

> git push origin master

Now I cloned remote git repo into another directory on my computer.

So now I have two local git repos associated with same remote repo.

When I do:

> git log --decorate

First repo shows all branches I made and origin/master.But second one shows origin/HEAD also.

Whys is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you push only your local `master` branch to your remote GitHub repo.

And if your remote repo only includes that one branch, that is the one you see in your second repo.

A [`git push --all -u`  would have pushed all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23892232/6309).
And even then, in your second repo, you would need (to see *all* branches):

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all --branches
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: But why is that first repo doesn't show origin/HEAD but second one does.

Comment: @Mandroid Because your first repo did not clone the GitHub repo: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17609521/6309 which references https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/6309. Your second repo did clone the remote GitHub one, and has consequently a `origin/HEAD`.